# Font being output smaller on iOS Safari?

Tags: html, ios, css, safari

Annoying issue that's making testing a little troublesome. Here is how iOS `Safari` renders a button element:

[image]

Here is how the same image is being rendered on a smaller screen in `Chrome`:

[image]

The computed styles for both of the buttons are as follows:

`Safari:`

[image]

`Chrome`

[image]

As you can see, everywhere where it matters the values are the same. Even `-webkit-text-size-adjust` is at `100%`. I'm honestly lost as to why it differs between the browsers right now.

Meta tag looks like so:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">`

Comment: Since the element containing the text (visible by its borders) appears to be bigger as well, likely the browsers zoom level is different between the 2

Comment: I agree with you. Trying to weed out zoom issues, I've updated the OP with the meta viewport tag and tried setting `*{ zoom:100%;}`, but that didn't solve anything.

Comment: I just tested your question (using SO website) on Chrome and FF, same issue, FF render everything bigger than Chrome ... bottom line, that is how it works, they have internal style sheets etc. and I wouldn't bother too much about this since a user can set these stuff themselves as well and nothing you can do about it.